# Update Foreign Key in table using another table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have duplicate entries in table A like:

```
id | name 
=========
 1    blue
 2    red
 3    blue
 4    blue
 5    red
```

In table B, the id from table A is a Foreign key and I want to update the Foreign Key with the minimum id from table A and then remove the duplicates from table A, so table B currently looks like this

```
id | tableAId
=============
 1      1
 2      2
 3      3
 4      4
 5      5
```

table B should end up looking like

```
id | tableAId
=============
 1      1
 2      2
 3      1
 4      1
 5      2
```

table A should end up looking like:

```
id | name 
=========
 1    blue
 2    red

UPDATE tableB
SET Id = (
SELECT MIN(Id) FROM tableB b
INNER JOIN tableA a on a.Id = b.Id
GROUP BY a.Name)
```

Comment: I have tried to update tableB based on a grouping of name and bringing back min(id), but this throws an error because I am trying to set one field to multiple values

Comment: Show us what you tried so we can take it from there.

Comment: @Crono - Updated post, but that doesn't work.  I basically want to update the deleted id's with the min(ids) before I actually delete the rows in table A.

Answer (score 0):

Find min values with a cte and use that to update tableb:

```
with cte as
( 
  select min(id) as id, name
  from tablea
  group by name
)
update b
  set tableaid = c.id
from tableb b
  inner join tablea a on a.id = b.tableaid
  inner join cte c on c.name = a.name
```

Then delete the unused records from tablea:

```
delete a
  from tablea a
where not exists 
(
  select * from tableb b
  where b.tableaid = a.id
)
```